# My is_prime function fails on 9, and I don't know why?

Tags: python, function

I have a bit of a problem. I am writing an `is_prime` function on, but whenever I run it, it fails on `is_prime(9)`, and I cannot see why:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2: ##because negative numbers, 0 and 1 are not prime##
            return False
    elif x == 2:
            return True
    else:
        for n in range(2, x):
            if x % n == 0:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

it returns `True` for some reason on `is_prime(9)`?

Comment: erm... You might want to think about this again

Comment: Note that `n` doesn't need to be checked up to `x`. The square root of `x` is enough.

Comment: range(2, x) is also overdoing it, every number is a prime or is composed by primes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because the function does not check *all* eligible divisors until it returns.

Instead, it exits early with `True` if `x` is not divisible by 2, which is not what you want for odd numbers (e.g. `9` is not divisible by `2`, yet it's not prime).

Instead, you want to try *all* possible divisors from `2` to `x-1`, and then return if `x` is divisible by none of them.

To do so, rewrite as such:

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2: ##because negative numbers, 0 and 1 are not prime##
            return False
    elif x == 2:
            return True
    else:
        for n in range(2, x):
            if x % n == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: Also, just for performance benefit, you should just be checking till `int(n/2)` , because no number after `int(n/2)` would be divisble by n

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: much better now. :-)